# Edit placeholder html after entering username

Tags: javascript

To save space (and keep things more compact) I added a input box with a placeholder stating

```
<input id="username-search" placeholder="view another users work">
```

after adding the username, I'd like to change the text of the placeholder to something like

```
<input id="username-search" placeholder="viewing -theuser-'s work">
```

as well as remove the text added to the input box by the user, as when text is entered, the placeholder disappears.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `placeholder` attribute dinamically as you need in an `onchange` event handler for the `<input type="text">` :

```
<input id="username-search" placeholder="view another users work"
               onchange="changePlaceholder(this)">
<script>
function changePlaceholder(input){
    if (input.value == '') { 
        input.placeholder = "view another users work";
    }
    else {
        input.placeholder="viewing " + input.value + "'s work";
        input.value="";
    }
}
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QjMLn/).

Take into account that the `<input>`'s value will be cleared after `onchange()`, so you might want to keep an `<input type='hidden'>` with the last inputted value if there's something you wish to do with it outside `onchange`.

Comment: both answers work fine but I used this code, hence the the right answer tick, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple really. Try this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('username-search');
input.onclick = function() {
    input.setAttribute('placeholder', "viewing " + input.value + "'s work");
    input.value = '';
}
```

Type something in the box, and then click on the box. The value will be removed, but the placeholder will update with "viewing Adam's work".